# JavaScript. Opening window with some content

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm new to JavaScript, so I've a question about it. I tried to google, but didn't find any information. So. I need to open chart in a new window, but not in browser window, in some kind of a custom window. So what's the idea. There is some element on a page, for example image. And when user clicks on it, chart appears in a custom window.

Here's the example: http://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/. As we can see, when we click on "Simple Column Chart" image, some kind of a window appears (but it's not a browser window, as I assume), and there's desired chart on this new window.

So my question is, how to implement such thing, when user clicks on some element and window (not browser window) with something (chart, in this case) appears?

Comment: What you're describing are called modal windows. [Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), [another example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin).

Comment: Hi, this is what is known as a modal pop up, please take a look online knowing the term. As a current reference, take a look at **[CodyHouse](https://codyhouse.co/)** and at **[one of their examples](https://codyhouse.co/demo/simple-confirmation-popup/index.html)**, there are many implementations so have fun looking around. Once you begin working on this and have any specific questions, feel free to write a **[Minimal Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** to base your questions upon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a very basic one for you my friend:

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/0eqwpwuz/1/

basically a new div thats `position:fixed` with a background. and the actual content in a new div inside of that.

play around with the html/css.

There are more ways to do it, but using jQuery is the fastest and easiest in my opinion. fadeIn and fadeOut are jQuery functions you can use out of the box, so you get a nice fade effect. otherwise you can just set the display to block

html:

```
<button class='open-modal'>
  open modal
</button>
<div class='modal-background'>
</div>
<div class='modal-box close-modal'>
  <div class='content'>
    modal
  </div>
  <div class='vertical-mid-hack'>

  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.modal-background {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.modal-box {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
.vertical-mid-hack {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
```

js:

```
$(function() {

    $('.open-modal').on('click', function() {
    $('.modal-background').fadeIn();
    $('.modal-box').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.close-modal').on('click', function() {
    $('.modal-background').fadeOut();
    $('.modal-box').fadeOut();
  })

});
```

Comment: lol thank you for whoever gave me the down vote